# How to show a custom page output in TeamCity build status window

Tags: teamcity

I want to publish a jpg graph image or a table of them in TeamCity's build status page.

I'm trying to use the plugin [Build Result Decorator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12599-build-result-decorator) for TeamCity to add a results page which doesn't seem to be working as expected. Wonder if anyone has a solution. When installed it creates this area (highlighted below) in the build status page, and should render a html in there.  But it shows a download file requestor instead of rendering the HTML.

[image]

Im testing with a basic page

```
<html><body>
<h1>hello TC</h1>
</body></html>
```

I've added that like this:

[image]

Here is the config as code along side the NUnit xml feature.

```
features {
    feature {
        type = "BuildResultDecorator"
        param("artifactFilename", "status.html")
    }
    xmlReport {
        reportType = XmlReport.XmlReportType.NUNIT
        rules = "**/result.xml"
    }
}
```

Has anyone got this working correctly ?  Or is there an alternative to this?

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out: This is possible without plugin.

Under the Project setting you add a Project Level report or Build level report (which will create a tab in either of those screens) and point it at a html artifact that you saved in the build. Then in Global settings you can either disable protection in a secured environment or specifically provide a URL to retrieve the html artifact.

Documented here

[Publishing 3rd Party reports](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/including-third-party-reports-in-the-build-results.html)

[Global settings for artifacts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/2021.2/teamcity-configuration-and-maintenance.html#artifacts-domain-isolation)